# Is nginx better than Tomcat when each request must be processed by JVM?

Tags: performance, tomcat, servlets, nginx

As Title, nginx process static file better than Servlet Container like Tomcat/Jetty. So use nginx for port 80, and proxy dynamic request to Tomcat in common.

But if ALL request must through JVM?

Like a Restful Web Service or else.

Is nginx still better in Performance? Or some else advantage?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a noticeable performance difference if you use nginx as reverse-proxy for Tomcat. But you gain a lot of advantages if you do so:

- Start multiple Tomcat instances and use nginx as simple load-balancer
- Ability to redirect to a maintenance-site while you take Tomcat down for maintenance
- Simpler SSL/TLS-Setup
- Support for virtual hosts when some host is not an Tomcat application

So I recommend to always use a reverse-proxy like nginx for Tomcat applications.